# Custom vs. non-custom attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

Something which implements the `ICustomAttributeProvider` interface will allow you to get custom attributes that have been applied to it via the `GetCustomAttributes` method.  As I understand it, a custom attribute is basically a special class (ending in "Attribute" and extending the `Attribute` class) that is created to be applied to something like a method or class using the appropriate syntax (`[FooAttribute]` just before the method/class/etc. in C#, for example).  But if that is a custom attribute, what is a *non*-custom attribute?  I used to think that attributes that were bundled with .NET were non-custom, but `GetCustomAttributes` even returns me attributes like `System.ThreadStaticAttribute`, which are very core to the .NET framework.

Is there such a thing as a non-custom attribute, or is "custom attribute" just a tautology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the following has any relevance, but if you say

```
var a = typeof(string).Attributes;
```

you get a value of a flags enum type called [`TypeAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes.aspx). Maybe these flags are the "non-custom" attributes of the type?

Comment: I think this is probably about right.  Custom attributes are things that aren't "type attributes".

Comment: For more clarification, I just read this on MSDN: *"Nearly all the Reflection classes can have attributes associated with them. Attributes can be standard (public, private, HelpString) or custom."*

Comment: To expand a little on this, `TypeAttributes`, `MethodAttributes`, `PropertyAttributes`, `FieldAttributes`, and maybe a few more are all the non-custom attributes you can find through the various `.Attributes` properties: `Type.Attributes`, `MethodInfo.Attributes`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Everything that derives from `Attribute` is a custom attribute.

"Attribute" is a generic term. Objects in the real world have innumerable attributes. Classes, members and parameters all have attributes that we can describe -- names, types, accessors, number of members, inheritance information, *etc.*

*Custom* attributes are things that we *tack on* -- aspects that we want to associate and use to describe, but which are not intrinsic.

Answer (score 2):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_%28CLI%29), quoting:

> Developers can add metadata to their code through attributes. There
>   are two types of attributes, custom and pseudo custom attributes, and
>   to the developer these have the same syntax. Attributes in code are
>   messages to the compiler to generate metadata. In CIL, metadata such
>   as inheritance modifiers, scope modifiers, and almost anything that
>   isn't either opcodes or streams, are also referred to as attributes.

See also the CLI specification about extending metadata, where references are found to the term "custom" attributes (e.g. I.9.7 in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)