# What is a custom attribute?

Tags: .net

What is a custom attribute? What is the difference between the 'normal' attributes on a type and a 'Custom attribute'? To be clear, I'm referring to the attributes returned by `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`. Aren't all attributes custom? If not what other attributes exist on a type?

Comment: I guess (and it's just a guess) that by _custom_ they mean attributes that a type is explicitly decorated with, as opposed to implicit ones, like size, type, and so on.

Comment: What attributes are you talking about?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError has the right idea. I could actually probably answer this question now after having done a bit of research but lets see what others have to say on the topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom vs. non-custom attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387551/custom-vs-non-custom-attributes)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel yeah I suppose this is a duplicate of that. Although, the question was edited... That doesn't contain answers to my first and main question which was just "what is a custom attribute".

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: it's a little inbetween the lines but "Everything that derives from Attribute is a custom attribute." seems like the answer. If you'll try it out, you'll notice that even compiler-injected attributes like `dynamicallyInvokableAttribute` are part of `CustomAttributes`. The ones that are part of `Attributes` seem to be things that make up a member's definition in IL. Though I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel something along those lines would be a good answer if you want to convert it to that.